Is there a way to determine users with the most questions?
I want to see who the most active users are on ELL, in terms of questions posted. Is there a way I can determine it?

Questions like this can be answered with the Data Explorer if you know a bit of SQL.
Here is a SQL query which produces the list you want. Note that deleted posts are not taken into account, and that the data is refreshed only once a week, on Sunday morning. The latter should not really matter for this type of query.


I believe you are the best person to reply to https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6029/need-to-mark-inbox-read  I think it should probably be tagged [tag:bug] but I'm not an expert on these things.

You need to intervene, as soon as possible. There is a user with at least 8 different accounts flooding the site with their nonsense.  Please, see my flags.

Thanks, I was on holiday, but one of my colleagues and SE staff have cleaned up a lot of posts and suspended quite a few accounts.

Thank you for taking the time to comment.
