Need to mark inbox read
It seems to me that until recently, if I clicked & followed on a link in my Inbox, the little white-on-red number reduced by one, and if I had read all of the new ones, it vanished. Just recently, it seems that I have to click 'Mark all as read'. Has something changed, or am I missing something obvious? Using Google Chrome on Windows 11.


That's been going on for me, off and on, for months. I just try again.

@AndyBonner - I've found that it doesn't do it in Firefox, so I just use that browser for SE. It does do it in Edge, but not in Thorium (a Chrome fork).

I've been exclusively firefox/linux for years, but I've only started noticing this problem in recent weeks (maybe 2-3 months, I don't keep a diary).

@FumbleFingers - It's not doing it in Firefox or Opera either on my Debian 11 (Bullseye) box, or on my wife's Windows 11 laptop, all latest versions.

@MichaelHarvey This issue also reported on Meta Stack Exchange: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/401070/1376393

Another thing - in Google Chrome and MS Edge, if I left click on the Inbox icon, the menu drops down for an instant and vanishes, too quickly for me to read the items and click on one. This does not happen in Thorium (a Chromium fork), Firefox, or Opera.
